# Moving overlapping Pictureboxes at runtime causes lag in repaint

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have 2 movable pictureboxes which allow the user to move images around and align them how he want

As I drag picturebox A over picturebox B , there is a trailing part of the image of A showing into B.  It dissapears very quickly.  This is the same thing you would see on very old Windows with bad resolution.

The particularity of it is that it only shows within the static picturebox, not the empty space underneath.  I've been fiddling with suspend layout and resume layout without much luck.  Any suggestions?  I am also open to changing the control type from Picturebox to something else if that will help.

```
public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        var control = sender as Control;

        control.SuspendLayout();

        Point pt = new Point(mouseEventArgs.X, mouseEventArgs.Y);

        control.Left += pt.X - _startDraggingPoint.X;
        control.Top += pt.Y - _startDraggingPoint.Y;


        control.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I went with a different solution.  We used DevExpress's document manager to hold our image controls.  It took a bit of work but it works better and the results are smooth.

Comment: How can somebody downvote my own solution?  Explanations please?

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly inevitable problem in Winforms, it is caused by you using multiple controls and visible because of the way controls are rendered to the screen.  One by one.  Double-buffering doesn't solve the problem, it applies only to the rendering of each individual control and PictureBox is already double-buffered.  In fact, it makes the problem *worse* because double-buffering doesn't come for free and delays the paint routine.

The biggest reason it is visible is because your PictureBox control is slow at painting the image.  That happens when you ask it to scale the image and expect it to render a nice looking small image from a large one.  This re-scaling takes time, particularly if the image is large, and is done every time the control draws itself.  You fix it by pre-scaling the image yourself so the control doesn't have to do it.

A real fix would be to not use any PictureBox controls at all but simply have the Form draw the images.  Now double-buffering solves your problem.  You'll of course lose a lot of convenience, including the built-in scaling that PB performs and the hit-testing you get for free.  Not actually that difficult to implement.

There is a magic incantation available in Windows that can *potentially* solve the problem without you having to do any work to improve your code.  You can ask it to double-buffer a window along with all of its child controls.  Everything gets rendered into an off-screen buffer, the result is blitted to the screen.  Paste this code into your form:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

This *can* cause paint artifacts, if they are too detrimental then you'll have to improve your code instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It would not be difficult to simply graphics.draw the images into rectangles. I do this in other forms.  Problem is that the click and drag events would have to be caught on the Form and i specifically want them to be in the control.  This is because the feature is a add on and i do not want to corrupt the current architecture.  Do you have a recommendation that would keep the click drag events in the picture controls and not the container form?

Comment: Well, you already know the positions of the images or you couldn't draw them in the right spot in the form's Paint event handler.  So figuring out which one is being clicked in the MouseDown event handler is not difficult either.

Comment: I think you miss-read.  I can detect (and in fact i do this in another program) which is being clicked, but using the graphics to draw them means it's the container which is doing the detection.  I need to keep the container intact since it's main purpose is not this function.

Comment: Well, whatever, the container's Paint and MouseDown event then.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property "DoubleBuffered" on your controls to true. This may help to reduce flickering.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.80).aspx